# DNS - domain conflict?

Tags: domains, web-development, dns, domain-registrar

I was given two domains: `domain.com` & `domain.info` (they are on GoDaddy).

And I was also given two servers, `107.105.38.99` - Rails app and `107.107.90.17` - Wordpress platform, on Digital Ocean.

At first, I was instructed to associate domain.com with the `107.107.38.99` (Rails app). Then I was instructed to de-associate this IP with `domain.com` and associated the `107.107.90.17` with the domain name `domain.com`.

Then I was instructed to associated `domain.info` with the `107.107.38.99` (Rails app).

Right now, when I go to `domain.com` the WordPress platform (`107.107.90.17`) loads fine and that is what is expected. But when I go to `domain.info` for the Rails app (`107.107.38.99`) I get redirected to `domain.com`. This is not expected and this is really weird for me.

When I ping `domain.info` I get this:

```
PING domain.info (107.107.38.99): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 107.107.38.99: icmp_seq=0 ttl=50 time=74.601 ms
```

Which is the expected result showing the correct IP but I don't understand why I get redirected to `domain.com`...(which when I ping is:)

> domain    64 bytes from 107.107.90.17: icmp_seq=0 ttl=50 time=75.057
>   ms

The PTR Records on Digital Ocean are as follows:

```
IP Address  PTR Record
107.107.38.99   domain.info.
107.107.90.17   domain.com.
```

and the DNS configurations on Digital Ocean are:

> **domain.com**
>
> A: @ 107.107.90.17
>
> CNAME: * @
>
> **domain.info**
>
> A: @ 107.107.38.99
>
> CNAME: * @

I am not sure what the issue is, if you have any clue please let me know, I will be really grateful. If you need any other info let me know.

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place. Redirects are nothing to do with your DNS, but instead they're generated by your web server config, and that's what you should be asking about.

Comment: @MikeScott you were right! Fixed it! I did not configure nginx correctly! You are awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this was a problem specific to your setup that is now solved, so closing.